# Как сделать связь один-ко-многим в sqlite3?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, связывание-данных

Первая таблица - это стрекозы, их 12. Вторая - это виды стрекоз, их 2. Мне нужно связать, чтоб стрекозы, с 1 по 6, были прямокрылые. С 7 по 12 - были разнокрылыми. Как это сделать?

Мне нужно задать внешний ключ для таблицы Стрекозы? Нужно ли сделать нормализацию, если да то в какую нф?

И с помощью каких средств делается связывание таблиц?
С помощью кода (у меня программа на python)?
С помощью SQL-запросов?
С помощью DB Browser for sqlite?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте первичный ключ в Kinds и внешний ключ в dragonflies,так вы сможете распределить стрекоз по видам и избежать возможных ошибок. Тут нормализация не нужна. Я делаю связывание таблиц в workbench, тут зависит от вашего вкуса, где вам удобнее ее делать.